# How to grant access to Qt5 libraries compiled through conda?

Tags: bash, conda

I downloaded a package `Rcount-multireads`. It requires Qt5 libraries. I am working on a Linux server without admin rights and use the conda environment. I installed Qt5 via conda. Running `./Rcount-multireads` should result in printing of the program parameters but gives me the following error:

```
./Rcount-multireads: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Widgets.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I found `libQt5Widgets.so.5` in `/software/miniconda3/envs/repeats/lib/`. How would I be able to grant access to those libraries?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/software/miniconda3/envs/repeats/lib/`" may help. It updates the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environmental variable

Comment: Thanks! Tried it, but unfortunately the problem still remains.